# How to use Google Tag Manager with Angular 4 Correctly?

Tags: angular, google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

I have a single page application built using Angular 4 . 
I have put the GTM code snippet just below the body tag in index.html.
Then in the Google tag manager panel i created a History Change event. [As mentioned in the documentation](https://www.pmg.com/blog/tracking-single-page-web-apps-google-tag-manager-analytics/)

When i user registers there are 3 steps 
1) step once (when i click on the email link i come to this page)
2) step two (once step 1 is completed and click on next step 2 opens )
3) step three (once step 2 is completed and click on next step 3 opens )
4) step four (once step 3 is completed and click on next step 4 opens )

```
But I cannot track my goals correctly for step 4.
```

Google analytics for step 4 says only 2 but the actual count from my admin is 92 
But for step 1 is tracking correctly.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Goals are counted once per session. Maybe the problem is here.

Comment: @cliff , the Title of that question looks pretty misleading: you just have an issue with the Goal configuration not with making GA / GTM behave properly in Angular 4. Would you mind fixing it ?